# How did wizards talk/exchange messages with each other over long distances?

Tags: harry-potter

I was wondering if there was any way in the wizarding world that people separated by long distances could exchange messages or talk to each other INSTANTLY. I know they generally used owls but it usually took some time for owls to deliver the letters. They could appparate but that presents some problems like not knowing EXACTLY where the other person is at that time, or if you were underage. Why didn't the wizards use telephones?

Comment: The Floo Network.

Comment: But both have to be near a fireplace.. And if they were in a Muggle locality??..

Comment: If they were in a Muggle locality they wouldn't be allowed to use magic, or probably even refer to the fact that there were wizards. And they certainly don't seem to have central heating in their houses; fireplaces are much more widespread than you might think.

Comment: @Rand al'thor - I think that is the answer right there. All wizard homes would surely have a fireplace and even public buildings like the Ministry are seen to have them. Then you just don't need a telephone. (Dumbledore invented the Patronus messenger didn't he, so most can't use that).

Comment: Does "instantly" mean faster than light? And does "exactly where" mean bypassing the uncertainty principle?

Comment: @ThruGog No indication that Dumbledore invented the Patronus messenger. I'm not even sure we ever see Dumbledore use it (he uses Fawkes to deliver a written letter in *Order of the Phoenix*). Kingsley, McGonagall and Arthur Weasley use it, from memory; admittedly they're all members of the Order so it's possible it's something Dumbledore discovered and only taught to other Order members.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist - IIRC JKR said in some interview that Dumbledore invented it. I think we see him use it in book four.

Comment: @Anthony Grist - The HP Lexicon tells me Dumbledore invented it, though I've not yet found another source.

Comment: Magic mirror? Old but classic.

Comment: @Oriol Hard science and Harry Potter is worse than [sex and unicorns](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/61010/hogwarts-so-why-arent-the-kids-doing-it/61012#61012).

Comment: @mayankbudhwani  Fireplaces are a necessity in the Wizarding World - every home has one, much like every Muggle house has a telephone or a computer. Until the mobile phone revolution in the last decade we had the same limitations. What to do if you were out and about? Use a payphone - I wonder if Wizarding communities have public fireplaces? Presumably places like The three Broomsticks allow anyone to use it - that's how the Weasley's got to Diagon Alley in CoS. And if you're in the middle of the countryside? Without good phone signal Muggles are just as isolated - except they can't apparate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most would use the Floo Network.

I think it is a very reasonable suggestion that every wizarding home would have a fireplace (they'd use them for more than us, they are fairly common anyway, Fred and George are surprised that the Dursley's is blocked up). Floo Powder is inexpensive (two Sickles a scoop according to Pottermore) and we see the Weasleys teach Harry to use it at the age of twelve. (Yes, it goes wrong, but not I think because it is advanced magic). We also see that public spaces like the Ministry of Magic contain several fireplaces, and I'd be willing to argue that Diagon Alley shops, The Leaky Cauldon, etc have them. In JKR's writing on Floo Powder on Pottermore, she also makes the bold claim that every wizarding house has a stock of it.

Also:
The coins used by Dumbledore's Army using the Protean Charm are an example of how there may be alternative ways to send simple messages without the need for a fireplace.

Finally, I'm afraid I don't think the Patronus is a logical answer for most wizards. I believe Dumbledore invented this (the [HP Lexicon](http://www.hp-lexicon.org/wizworld/communication.html) certainly says JKR said so) and I know that many wizards are incapable of producing one. Snape, for example, was [the only Death Eater capable of it.](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/72327/why-is-snape-the-only-death-eater-who-can-produce-a-patronus)

Comment: And what about more southern places than England? Do they have fireplaces too, just to enable Floo Powder communication/deplacements? I mean, if your friends were in holiday in the Carribeans for instance... Maybe the Wizards are just not so communication-addicted as we Muggles of the XXIe century, and are happy just to get a letter with an owl, even if it's not instantaneous

Comment: @LilyM considering that Muggles only 40 or 50 years ago were more likely to get a letter than a phone call from a distant friend. Those phone calls were Expensive. And until about 50 years ago, long-distance calls required time-consuming manual setup.

Comment: Both make good points. Don't most traditional homes, regardless of the weather, have fires of some sort?

Comment: Death eaters don't need patronesses  to communicate. Remember the way Bellatrix intimated about Harry at Malfoy manor via Dark mark

Comment: @Axelonet - I'm just using the fact no Death Eaters can use it, including some skilled witches and wizards, as evidence that it isn't a commonplace form of communication.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your definition of "long distance", but using a Patronus is an option. They've been shown to be capable of sending verbal messages a number of times in the later books, such as Kingsley Shacklebolt alerting attendees at Bill and Fleur's wedding that the Ministry of Magic had fallen, and can even be sent to multiple people/locations at once.

Another option is enchanted items such as the mirror that Sirius gives Harry in *Order of the Phoenix*, which enables two-way face-to-face communication (much like video calling does today) between whoever is holding each of the mirrors.

The exact range of these methods is unknown, as far as I know. It's unlikely that a wizard in England would be able to send a Patronus to a witch in North America (though we can't rule it out). The other consideration is the difficulty of conjuring a corporeal Patronus - although it's considerably easier to do in the comfort of your home or office than it is when in front of Dementors - which would mean it's only an option for more skilled, fully qualified witches and wizards.

Comment: In Pottermore JKR recently mentioned that they could communicate across continents for hundreds of years. Method unspecified.

Answer (score 0):

The mirror Sirius gave Harry comes to mind. It allowed for instantaneous communication regardless of location or distance. So there are methods other than a Patronus and Floo networks.

Also, a master can summon a house elvs regardless of distance.

Comment: This is true, but it’s a bit short. Can you expand on it a bit?